# Itemize exactly after description

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, description

I have an itemize environment in a description, unfortunately that doesn't look that nice. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description} 

  \item[Long description]
    \begin{itemize} 
      \item Foo
      \item Bar
    \end{itemize} 

  \item[Long description]
    \hfill \\
    \begin{itemize} 
      \item Foo
      \item Bar
    \end{itemize} 

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like.

[image]

The first itemize environment doesn't look nice. So I tried to fix it in the second itemize environment, but I get an extra paragraph, which is not so nice either. I could add `\vspace{-1cm}` to get rid of it, but that looks a bit like a hack. So my question is, what is the proper way of doing this? And if the solution with `\vspace{-1cm}` is the way to go, what do I put inside the brackets? Is there a command that gives my the height of one line?

Comment: you can use the same mechanism recommended to start a list right after a theorem heading: `\leavevmode`.

Comment: Perfect, that does exactly what I need. If you put that into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the same mechanism recommended to start a list right after a
theorem heading: `\leavevmode`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description} 

  \item[Long description]
    \leavevmode
    \begin{itemize} 
      \item Foo
      \item Bar
    \end{itemize} 

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: output of example code]

Comment: One possible approach seems to be instead `\item[Long description]\mbox{}`: is this acceptable as well?

Comment: @pluton -- yes, the `\mbox` will also work.  the necessary concept is that the `description` environment leaves you in horizontal mode, and anything that will get you out of that (without, in this case, producing any visible output) should work.